# Looking for a manga where the main character gets betrayed by his childhood friend who is a sage because he is jealous that he is close to the hero

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The main character gets stabbed by his childhood friend who is a sage, because he sees the sage with the other childhood friend who is a hero and the main character floats down a river, sees a dragon and then reincarnates.

Comment: Do you recall the appearances of any of the characters? What happens after he reincarnates? Is everyone involved in this opening male?

Comment: he reincarnates in the same body and he still remembers that the sage betrays him while young and then he tries to help the female hero the best he can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[I Am a Villager, What About It?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/murabito-desu-ga-nani-ka)*, aka *Murabito desu ga Nani ka?*.

> Born in the remote countryside, Ryuto’s childhood friends were a cheat of a **female hero and a wise man. One day at the age of 16, he was killed by a wise man, who was his childhood friend**. Soon, Ryuto was **reincarnated** as a villager. Get the “effort cheat” and the “knowledge cheat”! Although the status is the weakest, he is capable of even saving a hero! This is a story about Ryuto in the adventure world becoming the strongest villager on the ground!

The description is probably machine translated; "wise man" is the sage.

He is poisoned by his friend, the sage, not stabbed

[image: Poison the MC]

and is then dumped into the river, so the sage can continue to be with the hero. While floating along, he meets a dragon,

[image: Dragon, grants wish]

who handles the reincarnation.

Comment: yes this is it thank you